# Which one is faster? using matlab .m file or its .dll version?

Tags: dll, matlab

I'm running an algorithm and it's take a lot of time to execute(about 24 hours!). I just thought that if I create a .dll from my .m file and then run it, it will be much faster than what it is ? Is it a good idea or just wasting time :). thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your code, see this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/18427). If you've sufficiently optimized your code using vectorized operations, preallocated matrices, and converted divides to multiplies then the next step would be to run the profiler to see which parts of your code are taking up the most time and focus on those.

I've found that splitting up my problem into batches and running them in their own matlab instance that is dedicated per core helps a lot.

If after all of that it's still taking too long, then consider investing time into using mex. Granted there's a certain amount of time involved in now porting your code to C/C++.

Answer (score 3):

Check this [link](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/53587-speed-up-matlab-program-with-dll-file) out, where guys also suggested using [matlab-coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/).

I myself have experience creating a [mex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html) file from C code to be called by matlab code and that is pretty fast (I guess about the similar speed as standalone C code).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it is not a good idea, and yes, it probably is a waste of time. The MATLAB compiler does not actually compile M-files into machine code, just wraps them into a standalone executable and encrypts them. See this page for a detailed explanation: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94695.

Writing a mex function that perfrorms the same computations in C, on the other hand, will increase performance by orders of magnitude. I have experienced increases of literally a hundred times for some types of code. See this reference on how to write mex functions: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html.